# Java JDBC MySQL connection error: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

im trying to connect to the database but im getting this error.

this is the code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JDBCInsertValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysqljdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Drivers");

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * fom employee");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println(result.getString(1)+ " "+ result.getString(2));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error im getting.

run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysqljdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at JDBCInsertValues.main(JDBCInsertValues.java:14)

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

i have driver located on projects library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the driver name seems to be wrong

try

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

instead of

```
Class.forName("com.mysqljdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: that worked i guess but now im getting another error which is Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)   this is the code i use for connection      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Drivers","root","root"); any idea why?

Comment: ...or just omit the `Class.forName` statement altogether. It is usually not required these days. (Reasonably recent versions of Java use a different mechanism for loading JDBC drivers.)

Comment: @user3594235 If this answer solved your initial question you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021) it and then [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you now have a different problem you need to solve.

Comment: i'm new here sorry about that. his answer was right all i needed was right login info and it works now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using ANT. If it is the problem may be you've missed to include mysql library in build.xml

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same issue in my code. In your code you have to do following things:

1. change the first line of code in main method to Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
2. Now extract the MySQL Connector/J file like mysql-connector-java-5.1.32.zip.
3. You will have jar file mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar in the folder mysql-connector-        java-5.1.32 extracted at step 2
4. Now right lick on your project, go to Build Path >> Configure build path >> Libraries tab >> Add External JARs >> select mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar from the folder mysql-connector-java-5.1.32
5. Refresh and run your project. I hope these steps will solve your problem